# Save the table data in CSV format using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, export-to-csv

I retrieve the data from CSV file and store it in table using PHP. In this table I am using textboxes within td where I can edit the table data.
Now I want to store this edited data in the CSV file, but I am not able to store this edited data from this table to CSV file.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <br>
        <h1 style="text-align: center">* * * PROJECTS * * *</h1>
        <br>
            <input type = "hidden" id = "hide" name = "hide" value = "">
            <input type = "button" name = "submit" onclick = "document.write('<?php echoAlert() ?>');" Value = "SAVE">
        <br>
    </div>

    <?php
        function echoAlert()
        {
```

// What do I have to write here to store the data in CSV file?

```
    }
    ?>

    <?php
        $handle = fopen("data.csv", "w"); // this is my .csv file.
        $hide = $_REQUEST['hide'];    // here I will retrieve the data from data.csv file
        fwrite($handle,$hide);    // Here I will write the data from file to table

        $file = file('data.csv');
        $lines = count($file);
```

This is my table, here I write the file.

```
        echo'<table id = "projest" border = "1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
        style = "width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color: brown; background-color:gray;">';

        for ($i=1; $i<$lines; $i++) 
        {
            $part = explode(',', $file[$i]);
            echo'<tr>
                <td align= "center" width="5%">'.$part[0].'</td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[1].'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[2].'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[3].'></td> 
            </tr>';
        }
        echo'</table>'; 
    ?>
```

Here I can edit the data.... The problem is I want to store this edited data in this same csv file. But not able to store it.

Please give me some code to store this table data in a CSV file.

```
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use fputcsv()

[Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). For more information about this